# How to solve "Adding Application Insights to the project failed" during integration of Application Insights?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I tried to install Application Insights to my existing project. But getting the following error each time:

[image: Application Insights Error]

Steps I followed:

1. Created an Application Insights in Azure Portal
2. **Right click** and choose **Add Application Insights Telemetry** ... from
   visual studio 2015
3. Put my Azure id and pass and choose the Telemetry which I create on step 1.
4. Clicked on **Add** button

And finally getting the above error.

Also tried to add the SDK manually. And then repeated the same steps.

Till now no luck! Can anybody point out the things which might solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, we broke this the other day when we released 5.209, and just deployed a hotfix for it.

<del>To work around it, you can disable a new feature by creating a registry entry:</del>

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\AppInsightsGettingStarted]
"ConfigurationWindow"="Disabled"
```

<del>and restart VS and things should go back to normal.</del>

**Edit:** this was fixed today (6/14/2016) and deployed to the VS gallery as version 5.209.60613.1
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/82367b81-3f97-4de1-bbf1-eaf52ddc635a

If you have auto update enabled in VS, you'll automatically get a new version, otherwise you can manually go to tools -> extensions and updates to update the extension.